# How to check for special characters in a string?

Tags: c, string, pointers

How can I check whether there is a special character in my string when my input stored in a pointer? I tried this code but it seems that it will only check for the first char and not the whole string.

```
void EmployeeDetails(int count, account_s record[count]){  /* Function to get employee details */
    
    int i;
    char ch;
    EmployeeName: 
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){ // count here is the amount of employee from main function      
        
        printf("\nEnter employee name: "); 
        scanf("%s", record[i].EmpName);
        ch = record[i].EmpName[i];
     
        if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')){
```

Comment: what is the value of `count`?

Comment: You should probably learn about [the standard character classification functions in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: `i` seem to be a count of the strings you are trying to check. But you need also iterate over each string (with a nested loop and different index variable).

Comment: The second `[i]` in `ch = record[i].EmpName[i];` should be `[j]`, and enclose in another loop `for(int j=0; j<strlen(record[i].EmpName); j++)`. And then, you can use `if(!isalpha(record[i].EmpName[j]))` *for example*.

Comment: You're looking for the functions from [`ctype.h`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/).

Comment: In addition to what has already beeen commented, the overall design of your code is most likely very poor. [Edit] and show us more code (some lines before `for` and some lines after `if ((ch >= 'a'....`, and you'll most likely get valuable hints.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
void EmployeeDetails(int count, account_s record[count]){  /* Function to get employee details */
    
    int i;
    EmployeeName: 
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){ // count here is the amount of employee from main function      
        
        printf("\nEnter employee name: "); 
        scanf("%s", record[i].EmpName);

        for (j = 0; j < strlen(record[i].EmpName); j++)
        {
          char ch = record[i].EmpName[j];
          if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')){
            ...
        }
```

But the best way is to use on of the standard functions and replace `if((ch >= 'a'`  with this:

```
if (!isalpha(ch)) {
   ...
```

Even better: outsource the checking if there are special characters in the string to a function:

Replace the whole `for (j =`  loop with:

```
   if (ContainsSpecialChars(record[i].EmpName)) {
      ...
```

with `ContainsSpecialChars` being:

```
int ContainsSpecialChars(const char name[])
{
   // Returns 1 if name contains a special character. Otherwise returns 0.
   //
   // I let you write this as an exercise
}
```

Don't forget `#include <ctypes.h>` for the `isalpha` function.